# How can I compare two co variance matrices in R?

Tags: r, covariance

I need to test the equality of two co variance matrices for my two subsets:
trains[1:5, c(3,6,8,11)] and trains[6:10, c(3,6,8,11)].
Should I be using a boxM test or something similar? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `compareCov` from the package `covmat`.

As an example I will use the `longely` dataset from the `stats` package:

```
library(covmat)

(Cl <- cor(longley))
compareCov(Cl, Cl, labels = c("Robust Croux", "Robust"))
```

[image]

You can find more examples and details in the package's Vignette.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/covmat/vignettes/CovarianceEstimation.pdf

If you're asking how to select the most appropriate statistical test, then that's more of a question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), like Ben Bolker just commented.

Comment: I think the OP is asking what *statistical* test they should use, which makes this a question more for CrossValidated ...

Comment: Okay thanks, am I able to use boxM test for this as well as compareCov? and if so what would the coding be for it? Thanks guys

Comment: @JSlocombe95 I don't think so, but if you want to use Box's M-test there are several packages that do that, including `heplots`. This breaks boxM all down for you: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/heplots/versions/1.3-1/topics/boxM `boxM( cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, data=iris)` . If your question is answered please click the check mark.